# Problems with Knockout and viewModel

Tags: knockout.js, devextreme

I´ve got the following in my view:

```html
<div data-bind="dxTextBox: { onFocusIn: onEnterSearch, placeholder: 'suche...', showClearButton: true , value: ''}"></div>
<div data-bind="dxButton: { onClick: 'SearchCustomer', text: 'suchen' }"  style="width:100%;"></div></div>
```

and this in my js file:

```
function DoSearch() { alert('DoSearch');}

function clearSearch() {                
        alert('clearSearch');
}

var viewModel = {
    ////  Put the binding properties here
    SearchCustomer: DoSearch,
    onEnterSearch: clearSearch
};

return viewModel;
```

But now, when I focus the textbox, I get the alert 'clearSearch', and onclick on the button, I get a 404 error.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: A) Your code snippet doesnt produce anything.  B)  If you are getting a 404 error on a function like that it likely means a form is submitting.  I am not familiar with the controls you are using, but my guess is if you inspect your html you will see a form somewhere in it and the dxButton probably creates a submit button that is causing the form to fire.  If you can modify the ko.customBindings do so to change the button to a non submit button.  Else, add event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation to the doWork method assuming event is something you have access to in the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According this [article](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/SPA_Framework/Navigation_and_Routing/?version=16_1#Navigate_to_a_View):

> When defining a widget, specify a URL (a string or an object) as a handler for a widget event (assign the URL to the corresponding option or pass it as a parameter to the on method). For a better UI design, navigate to views using the events that fire as a result of clicking a widget or a widget element.

So, this event handler `onClick: 'SearchCustomer'` navigates you to the 'SearchCustomer' view that isn't defined.

If you want to use the `viewModel.SearchCustomer` method as the `onClick` event handler, just remove the quote symbol from the binding string:

```
<div data-bind="dxButton: { onClick: SearchCustomer, text: 'suchen' }"></div>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru55929p/), as well.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!